# Series Convergence check

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm analyzing for convergence the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k^p}$$, where $a,p>0$.

I believe that the series convereges if $a<1$, diverges if $a>1$, and if $a=1$, then it diverges if $p\leq1$ and converges if $p<1$.  I am having trouble formally proving the "series convereges if $a<1$, diverges if $a>1$" part.

Comment: Ratio test gives $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t_{k+1}}{t_{k}} = a$, so it follows as your intuition suggests. If $a=1$, then use the integral test and you get the desired result.

Comment: I guess a typo. "converges if $p<1$" is probably "converges if $p>1$"

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ratio test: $|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \dfrac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)^p}\cdot \dfrac{n^p}{a^n} \to a$. So if $ a < 1$, it converges, and diverges otherwise.

For the case $a = 1$, then you get a $p$-series so it converges if $p > 1$. But for your question, I focused on the cases you asked for: $a < 1$ and $a > 1$.

For the limit: $\dfrac{n^p}{(n+1)^p} = \dfrac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^p} \to \dfrac{1}{1} = 1$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: how can i formally show the limit? im having trouble because p is any real number

Comment: What about $a=1$? In this case we have the convergence for $p>1$. Isn't it?

Comment: I just included the case a = 1 in the edit.